# Change VBox Child

Tags: javafx, controller, vbox

I have a left VBox with Hyperlinks and a right Vbox that should display the items of the Hyperlinks.For e.g. i got the Hyperlinks "bar-chart" and "rectangle". If i click on barchart the rightvbox should display a bar-chart.
and if i click now on"rectangle" the right vbox change and show now a rectangle.

I dont know how to change the  right vboxchild from the actual used controller without open a new window.(with the same layout only with another right vbox)
I think there must be sth like rightvbox.getChildren().set??? 
and add all Items.

I use JavaFX Scene Border.( Have at the moment 2 FXML data with same layout only the right vbox is different is it possible to load all childrens of the vbox of 2nd fxml and update the actual used Controller? )

[vbox1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxhPy.jpg)

if i click on the hyperlink "Forschung" the right vbox should look like this:

[vbox2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMwDm.jpg)

Comment: It's hard to follow your descriptions. Can you post some code to show what you are doing?

Comment: Maybe the pics showing you what i mean. But thank you for helping me.

Comment: Yes, obviously a screenshot is exactly the same as code.

Comment: of course not but at the moment i dont have code to do this. Cause i dont know how this works with getChildren().setAll() and what i should insert there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just looking for

```
rightvbox.getChildren().setAll(...);
```

and just pass in all the nodes you want `rightvbox` to contain. (Can be just one node, or even no nodes if you want to clear it entirely.)

If you know `rightvbox` always just contains one item, then you can do

```
rightvbox.getChildren().set(0, node);
```

where `node` is the node you want it to display.

Comment: yes i want add more nodes so it is setall 
but i dont know how i should create nodes to add them to the vbox.